# Find the probability x<1/4

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

Given that x<0, find the probability x<1/4
F(x)=a cosπx (-1)/2<x<1/2, 0 oetherwise.

I got an answer of 0.3535. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Vaishali Sampath: HI.welcome to MSE. what did you tried?   have you found $a$   .try this link $$\\ \to$$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/psskahrdac

Comment: @Khosrotash
 Yes, I found a and the value of a is pi/2.

Comment: @Khosrotash
Yes, Found a=pi/2

Comment: @ Vaishali Sampath : did you try the link ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the link but I couldn't get it. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I have to find the probability P(0<x<1/4). So, I have integrated pi/2 cos(pi x) from 0 to 1/4. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI:welcome to MSE: I think you miss $$F(x)=\int_{-\frac12}^x \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\pi x)dx\\\to F(x)=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac{1}{4} \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\pi x)dx=.8535...$$ you did like below $$F(x)=\int_{0}^x \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\pi x)dx \\\to F(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac14} \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\pi x)dx=.03535...$$   as a  visual hint:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bzr02rhvlr

Comment: But the book answer is 0.707.That's why I Had confusion,. now, got cleared. Thanks, @Khosrotash. The answer is 0.3535